# let sand run between/through my fingers?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

How do I describe that I let sand run between my fingertips?

Answer (score 0):

If the flow of sand through the fingers is thin, then "*to trickle*" may be used, or, as well, "*to seep*". For a trickling through something like a sieve, a filter, or the fingers, the preposition "through" is proper. There is also the option to use the corresponding noun.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/trickle_1?q=trickle)) ​**1** [intransitive, transitive] to flow, or to make something flow, slowly in a thin stream
> (+ adv./prep.) Tears were trickling down her cheeks.
> trickle something (+ adv./prep.) Trickle some oil over the salad.

- He would let the dry thin sand that he would scoop up by whole handfuls trickle slowly through his fingers.
- He was  letting the dry thin sand flow through his fingers in thin trickles.

Comment: Sand isn't *thin*.  What would that even mean?

Comment: @PeterShor No, it is not necessarily thin, but it can be; I find this remark  of yours strange; this seems such an idiomatic combination (collocation); I find plenty of examples here: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thin%20sand%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en. What is the point you are trying to make?

Comment: What is the difference between a handful of thin sand, and a handful of regular sand? Are the grains of sand smaller? We call that *fine sand* and not *thin sand*. The hits in your Ngram are generally talking about a thin layer of sand, but that's not the case for your sentences. Consider [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some+fine+sand+is%2C+some+thin+sand+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csome%20fine%20sand%20is%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor For instance, in this example "thin"  is used and there are others: "they are sufficiently exact to permit ascertaining whether the potential of a thin sand compares favorably with that of neighboring thick sands". Also, at the entry for "fine" the definition is "very thin or narrow" (OALD). The antonym can be "coarse" or "thick". Maybe you have never been on too many beaches…The sands can be of different varieties.

Comment: @PeterShor I am aware that on the page I refer you to are often found combinations such as "thin sand layer/bed/…", but that is not all. What would "thin sand" as opposed to "thick sands" signify in the example I extracted from that page? It seems to me that the coincidence verifies this idea that "thin" can be taken as meaning "fine".

Comment: LPH thank you very much for your response! That was what I was looking for! I wasn´t sure whether sand can run through fingers, as it doens´t literally go through but in between, but that´s good to know!